# В чем проблема PickerView отображение данных

Tags: xcode, swift

При выборе любого из пункта в PickerView то текст в texfField скрывается.
[Картинка](https://monosnap.com/file/wOK2ofFfS8XmAbUf79klvfhe1m6tRe)
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже на то, что у Вас установлен `secureTextEntry`.

Это может быть или в коде `texfield.secureTextEntry = true/false`, или же в `IB`.

Comment: Спасибо! За помощь)